# Are SKProductsRequestDelegate methods always called on the main thread?

Tags: ios, storekit, ios13

In iOS 13 I've received a few crash reports that appear to be a result of performing UI work on a different thread than the main thread after receiving `productsRequest(_:didReceive:)` and `request(_:didFailWithError:)`. The documentation does not state which thread these are called on but I believe it has always been the main queue. Are they being called from a different queue now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I confirmed with iOS 13.1.2 that they can indeed be called from a different queue: `com.apple.root.default-qos (concurrent)`. Eek.

The solution is to dispatch that work back to the main thread via `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: I consistently get `SKProductsRequestDelegate` methods called on the main thread on iOS 12, and on a different (not main) thread on iOS 13. I plan to call `NSThread`'s `isMainThread` to selectively dispatch UI processing to the main thread only if the current thread is not already the main thread. In contrast, `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`'s methods seem to be called on the main thread on both iOS 12 and 13. I'd wish Apple would document what thread the various delegate/observer methods are called in. In lack of that, a check to `NSThread`'s `isMainThread` seems like the right thing to do.